# onClickListener ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-intent

I have a list of contacts in my `Contacts` activity that is populated in this method:

```
public void allyGetAllDelegate(HttpResponse response, JSONObject result)
{
    if(result != null)
    {
        ListView listContacts = (ListView) this.listContactsView.findViewById(R.id.listContacts);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

        JSONArray toIterate;

        try {
            toIterate = result.getJSONArray("data");

            for(int i=0; i<toIterate.length(); i++)
            {
                adapter.add(toIterate.getJSONObject(i).get("name").toString());
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        listContacts.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

When I execute this line:

```
adapter.add(toIterate.getJSONObject(i).get("name").toString());
```

I want to set an `onClickListener` on each item and inside it, intent to another activity with extra `toIterate.getJSONObject(i).toString()`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: How about adding an OnItemClickListener to the ListView?

Comment: But how do I track which object I want to send as extra?

Comment: The third parameter passed in `onItemClick()`, usually named `position`, will be essentially the index of the object in the ArrayList.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 @Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
          //Do something when an item is clicked 
}
```

Comment: Used setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {...});
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can store `JSONObject`-s in ArrayAdapter and retrieve them later.

So your code becomes

```
public void allyGetAllDelegate(HttpResponse response, JSONObject result) {
    if(result != null)  {
    ListView listContacts = (ListView) this.listContactsView.findViewById(R.id.listContacts);

    final Mydapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

    JSONArray toIterate;

    try {
        toIterate = result.getJSONArray("data");

        for(int i=0; i<toIterate.length(); i++)
        {
            adapter.add(toIterate.getJSONObject(i));
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
         // handle exceptions here
    }

    listContacts.setAdapter(adapter);
    listContacts.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent i = new Intent(/*your intent*/);
            i.putExtra("extra", adapter.getItem(position).toString());
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    }
}
```

Also you will have to extend `ArrayAdapter` and override it's `getView`

```
class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<JSONObject> {

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    TextView tv = (TextView) li.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null);
    tv.setText(getItem(position).get("name"));
    return tv;
}
```

}

Comment: That will not work!
How the inflater will output an JSON in the screen? It will call .toString() and will print a lot of stuff that I don't want...

Answer (score 0):

I had to create a static attribute called `contacts` (that receives a JSONArray).
Accomplished using that attribute and the `position` argument.

Thanks.

```
listContacts.setAdapter(adapter);
listContacts.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id)
    {
        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), ContactProfile.class);
            intent.putExtra("person", Contacts.contacts.getJSONObject(position).toString());
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```